How to terminate application opened by python subprocess
I am trying to open a pdf file with the default application on macos, which is preview, with
import subprocess
doc = subprocess.Popen(['open', 'path_to_doc.pdf'])

and close it.
I have tried the solutions in How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True but none of them works.
process = psutil.Process(doc.pid)

results in psutil.Process(pid=6994, name='open', status='zombie', started='12:07:11'). process.children(recursive=True) is empty.
os.getpgid(doc.pid) results in ProcessLookupError: [Error 3]No such process. By checking Activity Monitor (An application to view processes), I find the pid of the application is always doc.pid+1. In case doc.pid == 6994, the pid of the application is 6995. I can close the app with os.killpg(doc.pid+1, signal.SIGTERM), but this seems subjective that might not always work.
I am aware of osascript on macos to close applications such as with the code
clo = subprocess.Popen(['osascript', '-e', '''quit app "preview"'''])

However I would like a solution across platforms.

The problem here is that when you call open path_to_doc.pdf, the open command is ephemeral -- it runs briefly and then it exits after launching some other program to handle the pdf file. There is no way for your Python code to know what process actually gets launched.

you could resort to lsof ..., a trivial example below ... , then use logic to determine if a given entry matches criteria (username,filename etc ) ....
consult lsof documentation for intricacies .
lsof -FuncL n/Users/ticktalk/Downloads/w_aaaa1364.pdf
p87598
cPreview
u501
Lticktalk
ftxt
n/Users/ticktalk/Downloads/w_aaaa1364.pdf


obviously wrapped in python ....
